# Reading in HTML/XML PDF file formats into R

Tags: html, r, xml

I am trying to parse a pdf by reading it into R as either an HTML/XML file. I am aware that I could read it in using the `pdftools` package. However if I were to read the link just as an HTML/XML file, I have been unable to access the data inside.

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
html_string="https://mchb.hrsa.gov/whusa11/hstat/hsrmh/downloads/pdf/233ml.pdf"
ht <-read_html(html_string)
nodes<-xml_find_all(ht, ".//body")


> ht
{xml_document}
<html>
 [1] <body><p>%PDF-1.6\r%\xe2ãÏÓ\r\n83 0 obj\r&lt;&gt;stream\r\nhÞ\u009cTË\u008eÓ@äSú'»çÑ3\u0096V+EA\\"V«$·\u ...
 [2] <html><p>\u009d@a ö¯\u0088Î÷Ü\\&amp;ÔÈýÐâÿZO^"j[FoQ)ÒÇq\n\u009b\u008dx\u0085\u008eß±µ\u009bõo\t­\u008f6¢ ...

> ht[1]
  $node
  <pointer: 0x00000000047901a0>
```

I tried the following functions as well

```
xmlTreeParse
xmlToList
xmlParse
```

How do I access the xml document content string inside? I am tring to make them objects that I can manipulate.

Comment: How do I access the text of the xml_document called 'ht' ? And be able to read the text inside as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xml_document `ht` includes 1x body and 13x html
you can use `html_node` or `html_nodes` from `rvest` to extract the pieces you need.

```
library(xml2)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

html_string="https://mchb.hrsa.gov/whusa11/hstat/hsrmh/downloads/pdf/233ml.pdf"
ht <-read_html(html_string)

ht %>% html_nodes("html") # look at all html nodes
ht %>% html_node("body") # look at body node
```

Accordind to your question it looks like you would like to have the body node as text, right?

You can get it with:

```
ht %>% html_node("body") %>% as.character -> text #get body node as text
text    
[1] "<body><p>%PDF-1.6\r%\xe2ãÏÓ\r\n83 0 obj\r&lt;&g...
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution using `pdfx`

```
# download file to your home dir
download.file("https://mchb.hrsa.gov/whusa11/hstat/hsrmh/downloads/pdf/233ml.pdf","233ml.pdf")

# get packages
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("sckott/extractr")
library(extractr)

#parse
pdfx(file="233ml.pdf", what="parsed")
```

Comment: I am webscraping these health links. Unfortuantly I cannot tell if it's a pdf or not. So I cannot use this. The link could be a pdf or an html file. Which is why I have to read it in and then look at the content inside.

Comment: can't you tag the pdf's and html file during the webscraping and process them according to their tag?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The link, often the case, does not a .pdf extention. The HTML tag is the class <a href="link">. The link itself may or may not have a .pdf extention informing you that it is a pdf.

Comment: could you add a test data set with different examples?